# Hide user defined functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I know you can restrict users from executing some functions in PostgreSQL. I was wondering if there’s a way to hide user defined functions from some users so that they can't see the code?

Comment: you can use `GRANT PRIVILEGES`  for users.

Comment: Check this link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248351/postgresql-9-1-access-tables-through-functions